# Get only the first row when exist a negative value else get the last positive value

Tags: postgresql, case, with-statement, negative-number

I have the next table

| Product | Plant | Store | Text | Week | Date | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | HelloWorld | 1 | 2001-01-01 | 20 |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | HelloWorld | 2 | 2001-01-08 | -15 |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | HelloWorld | 3 | 2001-01-16 | -20 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | HelloWorld1 | 1 | 2001-01-01 | 10 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | HelloWorld1 | 2 | 2001-01-08 | 20 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | HelloWorld1 | 3 | 2001-01-16 | 30 |

So I would like to get the row for the first negative value but if is not negative values then get the last positive value. Also restructured the table like this.

| Product | Plant | Store | Text | Date_Start | Stock_Start | Date_Finished | Stock_Finished |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | HelloWorld | 2001-01-01 | 20 | 2001-01-08 | -15 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | HelloWorld1 | 2001-01-01 | 10 | 2001-01-16 | 30 |

I try multiple query's but the one with the nearest result is as follows:

```
SELECT Product,Plant,Store,Text,Date, Stock FROM table
WHERE (Stock)<0 
order by Product,Plant,Store,Text,Date, Stock asc
```

Also I tried to use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` but I got the next error `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "FIRST"`.
The other query is as follows:

```
WITH added_row_number AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product,Plant,Store ORDER BY Date ASC) AS row_number
  FROM MM_STOCK
)
SELECT
  *
FROM added_row_number
WHERE (Stock)<0 AND row_number = 1;
```

But beware the data and if I add a case stament I got the error `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "CASE"` . Any help?

Comment: `Fetch first N rows only` is `LIMIT 1` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Zegarek Thanks but then its the same result If I replace fetch for limit then get me just 1 row for all the table and I need 1 row for each product.

Comment: The *1 for each* idea usually translates to a [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) if you need predictable order in which you select the top one, `limit 1` in a subquery otherwise.

Comment: Do you need any one record with negative `stock`, and any one record with positive, or do you consider them to be ordered by one of the date columns for the purpose of selecting the oldest/most recent one?

Comment: I need the first stock's negative value with its date and also the first stock's value with its date in order to calculate the difference between both dates, but if it's not a negative in the stock then get me the last value with its day (usually the last value correspond to the final week and its positive) all this operation for each product to obtain an  unique row for each product, plant and store.

Answer (score 0):

Some Subselects can be used, to solve this

```
SELECT "Product", "Plant", "Store"
  , (SELECT "Date" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store"  = t2."Store" ORDER BY "Week" ASC  LIMIT 1) start_date
  
  , (SELECT "Stock" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store"  = t2."Store"  ORDER BY "Week" ASC LIMIT 1) start_stock
    , (SELECT "Date" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store" = t2."Store" ORDER BY "Week" DESC LIMIT 1) en_date
  
  , (SELECT "Stock" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store" = t2."Store"  ORDER BY "Week" DESC LIMIT 1) end_stock
  FROM
 Table2 t1
  GROUP BY 
    "Product", "Plant", "Store"
```

| Product | Plant | Store | start_date | start_stock | en_date | end_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | 2001-01-01 | 10 | 2001-01-16 | 30 |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 2001-01-01 | 20 | 2001-01-16 | -20 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/frFbcJfS)

you don't need for this aggregation, i can't find a Version postgres that doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Product", "Plant", "Store"
  , (SELECT "Date" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store"  = t2."Store" ORDER BY "Week" ASC  LIMIT 1) start_date
  
  , (SELECT "Stock" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store"  = t2."Store"  ORDER BY "Week" ASC LIMIT 1) start_stock
    , (SELECT "Date" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store" = t2."Store" ORDER BY "Week" DESC LIMIT 1) en_date
  
  , (SELECT "Stock" FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1."Product" = t2."Product" AND  t1."Plant" = t2."Plant"
  AND t1."Store" = t2."Store"  ORDER BY "Week" DESC LIMIT 1) end_stock
  FROM
 Table2 t1
```

| Product | Plant | Store | start_date | start_stock | en_date | end_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 2001-01-01 | 20 | 2001-01-16 | -20 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | 2001-01-01 | 10 | 2001-01-16 | 30 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p8XBDQxR)

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I run the query I have the error `ERROR: Correlated subquery expression without aggregates and with limit is not supported`

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: i added  aVersion that works with aggregatipn

Answer (score 0):

> I need the first stock's negative value with its date and also the
> first stock's value with its date in order to calculate the difference
> between both dates, but if it's not a negative in the stock then get
> me the last value with its day

You could rephrase this as "latest positive stock per product, also latest negative per product", which implies

- if there's no positive stock for a product, you get only negative stock records,
- if there's no negative stock for a product, you get only positive stock records.

As mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196478/get-only-the-first-row-when-exist-a-negative-value-else-get-the-last-positive-va#comment136092088_77196478), usually the *1 per product* translates into a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/33trbMy8)

```sql
(select distinct on (product) * from test
order by product
         ,stock<0 desc
         ,date desc)
union
(select distinct on (product) * from test
where stock>=0
order by product
         ,date desc);
```

| product | plant | store | text | week | date | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | HelloWorld | 3 | 2001-01-16 | -20 |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | HelloWorld | 1 | 2001-01-01 | 20 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | HelloWorld1 | 3 | 2001-01-16 | 30 |